# How remove inherited variable in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry

How can I remove an environment variable inherited from a base image?

For example, when using:

image "myimage:a":

```
FROM alpine
ENV hello=world
```

I can override the variable in the descendant image like this:

image "myimage:b":

```
FROM myimage:a
ENV hello=none
```

And I even can make it empty:

```
FROM myimage:a
ENV hello=
```

But I want to remove the `hello` variable completely from `myimage:b` instead of making it empty, so that it doesnt show up in the GUI for container management software.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: what if `a` needs it for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not supported by Docker, there's a very old open issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465

This could be done by other tools that mutate container images, like Google's `crane mutate` or my own `regctl image mod` command. However neither of these support that feature at the time of this answer. That would make a decent feature request if you wanted to go that direction.

Otherwise, the best alternative I can think of is to rebuild a fork of image A without the variable set. A worse option would be copying the content from the other image into your own:

```
FROM scratch
COPY --from=myimage:a / /
```

But then you'd lose all of the settings, like the entrypoint, ports, other environment variables, along with squashing the layers losing any layer reuse and layer history details.

Comment: I dont care about loosing any ports/entrypoints/etc since the Dockerfile for image B is almost identical to my Dockerfile for image A. So thank you for the Scratch solution. I will do it that way, although its a bit unfortunate that I loose the layer cacheability